# UWP Package Install Script Doesn't Install Properly

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, uwp, installation

When you build an UWP app it also creates an install script as shown below. I've used it to install application quickly as through the GUI I need to uninstall the app and sometimes it doesn't uninstall fully and I need to troubleshoot using PowerShell.

[image: Install Script Explorer]

The issue is that this script doesn't actually install properly because recently I fixed an issue and did a build but if I install by running the script the fix is not seen/available in the running application. It was a script change not a visual change so it's still using old build of script?

However, if I uninstall and install by opening the package (`.appxbundle`) and clicking install it does function correctly.

So I don't know why that is happening. This script is auto-generated and I haven't changed anything but it still has incorrect functionality? Is this a MS bug (anyone know where I can report it)? Something I'm doing wrong? Can anyone who knows PowerShell spread some light.

[Here are the scripts.](https://gist.github.com/lordlycastle/bfbb0b05667968a41fbe3a00d2d4c48b)

The app was made with Unity 2018.4 LTS then package was built using VS.

Comment: I created an old and a new packages. First, I used powershell to install the old one and run it. Then I used the same way to install the new package. The powershell automatically closed my app and re-started it after the installation was complete. After installing the new one, the content of the app has been updated. So I can't reproduce your issue. Are my steps correct? If not, can you show more details about your behavior? And what's the issue you fixed?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT The change I made was in a C# script, it was literally a couple of lines of change and some visuals. I should mention is that the app is made with Unity and then VS builds its output into a UWP package. The steps are the same. This issue also happens on two other PCs as well; the same issue when using Install script. I just did another install w/ script of newer update and it's still staying on the first version with neither fixes. The resources aren't updating either; we have a config file bundled and it's still old one. The app version does update to latest installed.